# How do I fetch data from this column in pdo?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm very new to PDO. The issue I'm currently facing is that I'm trying to grab a users first name from a column however I have no idea how to fetch it properly. I've managed to find verify the user email with the email in the database now I just need to fetch the UserFirstName column and store it in a variable.

```
$data = array();
 if(isset($_POST['email'])){
  $data = $_POST['email'];


            if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                $data = $_POST['email'];

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserEmail = :UserEmail');
                $stmt->execute(array(':UserEmail' => $data));
```

Comment: So you're basically asking how to fetch a row with PDO?

Comment: `$stmt->execute(` should be `$result = $stmt->execute(` and `var_dump($result);`

Comment: @samayo it would rather make no sense to do that

Comment: It does if the query is right

Comment: @samayo check the linked question

Comment: @YourCommonSense Exactly!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change query to:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT UserFirstName FROM users WHERE UserEmail = :UserEmail');
```

To execute:

```
$stmt->execute(array(':UserEmail' => $data));
```

then to fetch single column

```
$result = $stmt ->fetchColumn();
print("name = $result\n");
```

for reference
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

Comment: It returns  Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in "$result = $stmt ->fetchColumn();"

Comment: That's because you need to bind the parameters, use the execute you already had in the question: `$stmt->execute(array(':UserEmail' => $data));`

Comment: Oh I see now! Thank you for clearing that up and taking your time!